# tcl regex doesn't work as expected when used with variable name

Tags: regex, grep, tcl

I am using tcl to perform some pattern matching. The following is the string that I am performing the match on:

```
ps -ef | grep ipqosmgr
root     17255 17136  0 22:34 ttyS0    00:00:00 grep ipqosmgr
root     28986 17731  0 Jun05 ?        00:02:01 /isan/bin/ipqosmgr
```

Typically I would want the 3rd line

```
root     28986 17731  0 Jun05 ?        00:02:01 /isan/bin/ipqosmgr
```

since I would like the process ID associated with the process.

When I use the following regular expression, it works as expected:

```
% foreach line [split $output \n] {
    if { [ regexp -nocase {root\s+([0-9]+)\s+.*(/isan/bin/ipqosmgr)} $line - value ] } {
        puts $line
    }
}
root     28986 17731  0 Jun05 ?        00:02:01 /isan/bin/ipqosmgr
% puts $value
28986
%
```

However, I would like this code to run for multiple processes and hence have put this in a function with *$process* which will hold the value of the process. When I use the same regex with the variable *$process*, it fails.

```
% puts $process
ipqosmgr
%
% foreach line [split $output \n] {
    if { [ regexp -nocase {root\s+([0-9]+)\s+.*(/isan/bin/$process)} $line - value ] } {
        puts $line
    }
}
% 
% puts $value
can't read "value": no such variable
%
```

I have no idea as to why its behaving this way and it would be really great if someone could tell me whats going wrong here and how to rectify it.

Comment: Use `"root\\s+(\[0-9\]+)\\s+.*(/isan/bin/$process)"` if you plan to use string interpolation.

Comment: If you're familiar with shell script programming, Tcl braces are like shell single quotes: no variable interpolation is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a double quoted string literal if you plan to use string iterpolation, and  mind escaping `[` and `]` to prevent interpreting them as commands as well escaping each `\` to define literal backslashes (e.g. with the shorthand character class `\s` here):

```
regexp -nocase "root\\s+(\[0-9\]+)\\s+.*(/isan/bin/$process)" $line - value
```

See the [Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/BFVe1R).

Here,

- `root` - a substring `root`
- `\\s+` - parsed as `\s+` - 1  or more whitespace chars
- `(\[0-9\]+)` - parsed as `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1 - 1 or more digits
- `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `(/isan/bin/$process)` - parsed as `(/isan/bin/ipqosmgr)` - Capturing group 1 matching a `/isan/bin/ipqosmgr` substring (or any `/isan/bin/` + `$process`).

Answer (score 2):

You can prepare the regexp with [`format`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm) as below:

```
foreach line [split $output \n] {
    set regex [format {root\s+([0-9]+)\s+.*(/isan/bin/%s)} $process]
    if { [ regexp -nocase $regex $line - value ] } {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

The problem with the way you were using the expression is that braces prevent variable substitution, and while you can use quotes instead for the regular expression, you will have to escape a lot of characters (square parens, backslashes for instance) and to avoid having to escape these, using `format` can be simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use variable substitution with the [`subst` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/subst.htm). Also if any of the `-nobackslashes`, `-nocommands`, or `-novariables` are specified, then the corresponding substitutions are not performed. For example, if `-nocommands` is specified, command substitution is not performed: open and close brackets are treated as ordinary characters with no special interpretation.

```
% set output "
root     17255 17136  0 22:34 ttyS0    00:00:00 grep ipqosmgr
root     28986 17731  0 Jun05 ?        00:02:01 /isan/bin/ipqosmgr
"
```

and with variable set

```
% set process "ipqosmgr"
```

You could very well do,

```
% foreach line [split $output \n] {
    if { [ regexp -nocase [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes {root\s+([0-9]+)\s+.*(/isan/bin/$process)}] $line - value ] } {
        puts $line
    }
}
root     28986 17731  0 Jun05 ?        00:02:01 /isan/bin/ipqosmgr
```

does the match as expected

```
% puts $value
28986
```